# Display waves that have non integer coordinates with only integers

Tags: java

I'm trying to move a cursor in a sin wave pattern but because the mouseMove function takes integers as parameters I can only move the mouse to coordinates on the wave where both the x and y values are integers. This is not a problem when the "height" of the wave is smaller but as it gets larger you can see the gaps more easily since the distance between two coordinates that have x and y values that are integers is larger. Is there a way that I can move the cursor to coordinates that are close to these non integer coordinates so that it will look like a complete wave?

```
import java.awt.Robot;

public class WaveMotion {
    public static void MoveMouseWave(int startX, int startY, int waveHeight, int waveLength, int speed) {


    int a = 0;

    while(a < waveLength) {
        int x = (a * waveHeight) + startX;
        int y = (int) ((Math.sin(a) * waveHeight) + startY);
        System.out.println(x + "," + y);
        a++;
        try{
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.delay(((speed * -1) + 10) * 100);
            robot.mouseMove(x, y);

        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can't you just round them? (Math.round(double x))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `mouseMove` takes integer parameters does not require you to use integers for the entire calculation. For example, it is not necessary to only pass integers to `Math.sin`, and in fact these will be converted to doubles anyway. You can use `double`s or `float`s for your intermediate calculations and then cast to `int` when computing the final value.

One other reason that your cursor will appear to be jumping from point to point isn't directly related to the fact that the co-ordinates are integers, but because you are stepping along x by a value equal to the `waveHeight` each time, which is a larger jump than the integer limitation imposes:

```
int x = (a * waveHeight) + startX;
```

Alternatively, you can step x by 1 each time (so no big jumps), and divide by `waveHeight` when calling `sin()` to reflect the fact that you have moved a smaller step along the wave:

```
int x = a + startX;
int y = (int)(Math.sin((double)a / (double)waveHeight) * (double)waveHeight) + startY;
```

Be careful to check for a `waveHeight` of zero to avoid division by zero errors. You could also change the type of `waveHeight` to `double` to avoid having to cast it. Because you are stepping a smaller distance each time, you will need to increase `waveLength` by a factor of `waveHeight` to get a wave of the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Given your program as it is it seems you want to move a on a circle by advancing 1 degree at a time. The sine will convert that motion on the circle to palindromic motion on the line. Only you have to realize that sine takes radians. Therefore:

```
int y = (int) ((Math.sin(Math.toRadians(a)) * waveHeight) + startY);
```

and to be consistent with the use of a

```
 int x = (Math.toRadians(a) * waveHeight) + startX;
```